# Where should I place this code in MVC?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, logic

My code works perfectly, BUT. Whats the best practice in this case?

Here is the code that is important.

This is in the controller.

```
    private IProductRepository repository;
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int productId) {
        Product prod = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        if (prod != null) {
            repository.DeleteProduct(prod);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} was deleted", prod.Name);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is the repository (both Interface etc)

```
public interface IProductRepository {
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    void SaveProduct(Product product);
    void DeleteProduct(Product product);
}
```

And here comes the repository..... (the part that is important) I want to point out though... that this is not a fakeclass as is pretty clear. The testing is done on fakeclasses.

```
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products {
        get { return context.Products; }
    }

    public void DeleteProduct(Product product) {
        context.Products.Remove(product);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Well first question:
When doing testing on this, I will make a two TestMethods on the Controller in "ControllerTest". "Can_delete_valid_product" and "Cannot_delete_invalid_product". Is there any point in having a testclass for the repository? Like "RepositoryTest", afterall the controller tests if the deletefunction works no need to test it twice right?

Second question: 
In this I test in the controller if the product exists, before trying to delete it. If it exists I call the deletefunction in the repository. This means that there should never be the posibility of an exception. BUT you could still create an exception in the repository if you send down null. (which cant happen here but you could still do it if you forget to check if null). Question is if the testing if product exists should be done in the repository instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Personally I create separate tests for my repositories/data access to ensure that it works properly.  The controllers themselves would be tested with mocks.
2. Actually it's entirely possible (just maybe not that likely) that someone could delete a product just as someone else is trying to delete it.  In this case you probably don't care/need to know that someone did though so I would probably just swallow that exception in the repository (though I would log it first).  In terms of null checking/defensive programming that's entirely a personal choice.  Some people leave checks like that to the entry points of the system where as others will build a layered defense that has additional checks throughout the code.  The problem is that these checks can get quite ugly which is a big part of why I wish [Code Contracts](http://www.infoq.com/articles/code-contracts-csharp) would gain more traction.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep logic out of the controller for the most part. A test of the controller action verifies if the repository is called, but the repository itself is mocked in that test. I would make the repository responsible for handling null checking.

Answer (score 0):

> This means that there should never be the posibility of an exception. BUT you could still create an exception in the repository if you send down null. (which cant happen here but you could still do it if you forget to check if null).

Or if it's deleted after you check it exists but before you delete it. Or if you lose connection to the repository (or will the method never return in this case?). You can't avoid exceptions in this way.